# Why am i getting runtime error, void type is not allowed here?

Tags: javafx, methods, instance

You probably think that it is a duplicated question but i don't need you to find an error, all i need is a decent explanation of why isn't that possible. A rough description of my problem is that i am trying to call a method to an instanced object. Specifically instance of the JavaFx UI component.

Exactly :

```
    vbox.getChildren().addAll(new Label("1").setTranslateX(100), l2);
```

All i want is not to intialize and set values many times like this :

```
    Label l1 = new Label("1");
    Label l2 = new Label("2");
    l1.setTranslateX(0);
    l1.setTranslateY(108);
    l2.setTranslateX(0);
    l2.setTranslateY(121);
```

If anyone knows if it is possible i would like to see this solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem is that setTranslateX() returns void, that means nothing. And nothing cannot be added to a collection. Next problem: setTranslateX() is final. You cannot override it. But you can create a new childclass of Label with a method which returns the object and sets the x-value. Only its name must be slightly different. Another possibility: create a method thats create a label and sets the translate-coordinates and returns the label.

Comment: Well thanks for the answer. I will do the changes @mayamar .